# react-router-bootstrap LinkContainer component fails with a TypeError (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-bootstrap

I have been using the LinkContainer from the react-router-bootstrap react library for a while but currently it is throwing this error when I import it:

> TypeError (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function

I have my very simple react application in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-blackburn-g31z2?file=/src/App.js) over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-blackburn-g31z2?file=/src/App.js)

Help me debug this please.

Comment: Beginning in v6 of react-router, `withRouter` was removed. See the [upgrade-guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) - *Along with the upgrade to v5.1, you should replace any usage of withRouter with hooks*

Comment: Okay if I get any trouble I'll ask for your help @Brian Thompson

Answer (score 1):

You have to options, either you downgrade your version (to v5.3.0) of react-router-dom so method withRouter will be available again (used by react-router-bootstrap) or you dismiss react-router-bootstrap and use the useNavigate Hook:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
<Nav.Link onClick={() => navigate('configuration')}>
```